# Need to take user to a different page when they click on a list item/ convert current list items to buttons?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I was trying to create a search function such that if a user searches for an item, the excessive items go away as they search on the toolbar and when they click on the item it takes them to the specific page for that item. Currently, I have this code which I salvaged by watching someone on youtube, I need help as I'm a total beginner. Thanks!

college_search.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/college_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testrun3.CollegeSearch"/>
```

CollegeSearch.kt

```
package com.example.testrun3

import android.content.Context
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.college_search.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.country_child.view.*
import android.os.Bundle as Bundle1

class CollegeSearch : AppCompatActivity() {

    var countries:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    var displayList:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle1?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.college_search)
        loadData()
        // country_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        college_list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,1)
        college_list.adapter = CountryAdapter(displayList,this)

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.college_search_menu)
        if(searchItem != null){
            val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
            val editext = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
            editext.hint = "Search here..."

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                    return true
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                    displayList.clear()
                    if(newText!!.isNotEmpty()){
                        val search = newText.toLowerCase()
                        countries.forEach {
                            if(it.toLowerCase().contains(search)){
                                displayList.add(it)
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        displayList.addAll(countries)
                    }
                    college_list.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    return true
                }

            })
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }


    class CountryAdapter(items : List<String>,ctx:Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

        private var list = items
        private var context = ctx

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder?.name?.text = list[position]
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.country_child,parent,false))
        }


        class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val name = v.country_name!!
        }
    }

    private fun loadData(){
        countries.add("Afghanistan")
        countries.add("Albania")
        countries.add("Algeria")
        countries.add("Andorra")
        countries.add("Angola")
        countries.add("Antigua and Barbuda")
        countries.add("Argentina")
        countries.add("Armenia")
        countries.add("Australia")
        countries.add("Austria")
        countries.add("Azerbaijan")
        countries.add("Bahamas")
        countries.add("Bahrain")
        countries.add("Bangladesh")
        countries.add("Barbados")
        countries.add("Belarus")
        countries.add("Belgium")
        countries.add("Belize")
        countries.add("Benin")
        countries.add("Bhutan")
        countries.add("Bolivia")
        countries.add("Bosnia and Herzegovina")
        countries.add("Botswana")
        countries.add("Brazil")
        countries.add("Brunei")
        countries.add("Bulgaria")
        countries.add("Burkina Faso")
        countries.add("Burundi")
        countries.add("Cabo Verde")
        countries.add("Cambodia")
        countries.add("Cameroon")
        countries.add("Canada")
        countries.add("Central African Republic (CAR)")
        countries.add("Chad")
        countries.add("Chile")
        countries.add("China")
        countries.add("Colombia")
        countries.add("Comoros")
        countries.add("Democratic Republic of the Congo")
        countries.add("Republic of the Congo")
        countries.add("Costa Rica")
        countries.add("Cote d'Ivoire")
        countries.add("Croatia")
        countries.add("Cuba")
        countries.add("Cyprus")
        countries.add("Czech Republic")
        countries.add("Denmark")
        countries.add("Djibouti")
        countries.add("Dominica")
        countries.add("Dominican Republic")
        countries.add("Ecuador")
        countries.add("Egypt")
        countries.add("El Salvador")
        countries.add("Equatorial Guinea")
        countries.add("Eritrea")
        countries.add("Estonia")
        countries.add("Ethiopia")
        countries.add("Fiji")
        countries.add("Finland")
        countries.add("France")
        countries.add("Gabon")
        countries.add("Gambia")
        countries.add("Georgia")
        countries.add("Germany")
        countries.add("Ghana")
        countries.add("Greece")
        countries.add("Grenada")
        countries.add("Guatemala")
        countries.add("Guinea")
        countries.add("Guinea-Bissau")
        countries.add("Guyana")
        countries.add("Haiti")
        countries.add("Honduras")
        countries.add("Hungary")
        countries.add("Iceland")
        countries.add("India")
        countries.add("Indonesia")
        displayList.addAll(countries)
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:id="@id/college_search_menu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />

</menu>
```

Comment: Add an  `OnClickListener` in the `onBindViewHolder()` of your adapter, decide the logic based on the selected Country (`list[position]`) and use `ctx` as context for Intent to start a new activity. What's the problem then?

Comment: Could you help me out a bit and tell me how and where do I use ctx I don't know what it does or actually I'm not gonna lie I couldn't understand any do what you told me

Comment: I've answered in detail. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create an `OnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder()` of your `CountryAdapter`

```
holder.name.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(context, YourActivity::class.java)
    context!!.startActivity(intent)
}
```

This is how you set an `OnClickListener` on an item in Adapter. Here's we're using intent to start a different activity when the item is clicked.

Now, `Intent` class in the above solution takes two parameters, First one is the `Context` which is the current activity with which user is interacting. This is used to pass the current focus where new activity should open. It must not be `null`. Second one is the activity's class you want the app to switch to. `Activity` opens in stack which means Last in First Out.

Next, you're starting the created intent by using `startActivity(Intent)`. But, as this is not an Activity, you have to pass the context to it as well. But, where's the context?

Here: `class CountryAdapter(items : List<String>,ctx:Context)`. See, you've already declared it as an argument and also passing it from the activity as `college_list.adapter = CountryAdapter(displayList,this)`. This `this` is the context you've passed to the Adapter.

I said use `ctx`. Why? because you've named the context `ctx` in your adapter which doesn't matter because it's a variable and you can name it as you like. Same context mechanism is needed in `Fragments`.

Also. remember, in activity you pass `this` as context as parameter but don't need it for invoking methods like `startActivity()`.

So, final result for your adapter's or a `Fragment's` `onClickListener` is:

```
holder.name.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(ctx, YourActivity::class.java)
    ctx.startActivity(intent)
}
```

In case of an activity is:

```
//In activity, you don't even need to pass the rootView to access the elemets as in adapter or Fragments.
name.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Now**, you just have to design a new activity for the item. Also, With so many multiple items, you wouldn't want to create as many activities. So, Create a same structured activity, pass the selected item to it and do whatever you want to do with the item.

You can do it by passing the selected item through intent using the `.putExtra()`.

```
//It takes two parameters: First one is the key name you want to give to the value passed
//Second one is the actual value you pass
intent.putExtra("SelectedCountry",list[position])
//This will put the selected country with the intent request.
//put it before just startActivity
```

Now, access it in the next activity as:

```
//Here, you have to use the data type based extra for the value you've passed.
//As we have passed a string, we're using getStringExtra, same for int getIntExtra()
//It takes the key name as the input, key should exactly match in both the activities
val selectedCountry = intent.getStringExtra("SelectedCountry")
//Now, do whatever you want with this country name in the new activity.
```

This is a very detailed answer, I hope you'll learn it all. Also, you'll learn eventually.

Comment: so i tried that as well, but for some reason im getting this error while implementing the Intent even though i have everything necessary imported already.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UaYuNiZVkGkCrMoiYl65ij83w4-2019C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @shivamrathore you're getting this error because you've used the code meant for Activity. You're using it inside an adapter, not activity so you should use code meant for adapter. Check the code for final result above which starts with holder.